# Firebase functions not being invoked

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate Stripe payments on my webapp using Firebase. I have cloned the code from the repository here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe and have followed the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments

From reading the documentation, I assumed that when a customer signed in through firebase authentication, their details would be added to a stripe_customer collection in the firestore. I realised this wasn't the case, and manually added a user to test the save card functions. Then I received the following error : "Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardSetup intent secret: value should be a client_secret string. You specified: undefined"

I have a blaze plan for firebase and have configured. From following the steps in the documentation, I assumed this would be working. I'm sorry this question is so vague, but it seems at every corner I'm getting another issue. Is there something very obvious I am missing that is stopping this code from working? I am trying to implement this for a friends business as a favor, and am getting really confused with Firebase. I am coding in Angularjs. Would greatly appreciate any help on this!

This is the code for the function to create a customer

```
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
        const customer = await stripe.customers.create({ email: user.email });
        const intent = await stripe.setupIntents.create({
        customer: customer.id,
  });
  await admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({
    customer_id: customer.id,
    setup_secret: intent.client_secret,
  });
  return;
});
```

And this is the code being called in the controller:

```
const firebaseUI = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
const firebaseUiConfig = {
  callbacks: {
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function (authResult, redirectUrl) {
      // User successfully signed in.
      // Return type determines whether we continue the redirect automatically
      // or whether we leave that to developer to handle.
      return true;
    },
    uiShown: () => {
      document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
    },
  },
  signInFlow: 'popup',
  signInSuccessUrl: '/checkout.html',
  signInOptions: [
    firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
  ],
  credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE,
  // Your terms of service url.
  tosUrl: 'https://example.com/terms',
  // Your privacy policy url.
  privacyPolicyUrl: 'https://example.com/privacy',
};
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((firebaseUser) => {
  if (firebaseUser) {
    currentUser = firebaseUser;
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('stripe_customers')
      .doc(currentUser.uid)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.data()) {
          customerData = snapshot.data();
          startDataListeners();
          document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            console.warn(
              `No Stripe customer found in Firestore for user: ${currentUser.uid}`
            );
        }
      });
  } else {
    document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'none';
    firebaseUI.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', firebaseUiConfig);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, Have you set your stripe key in the config for the Cloud Function?, are you testing this locally? if so have you updated your local store with those values?

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your help! I have set up my stripe key in the CLI as told in the document. I'm testing locally, but I'm not sure what you mean but updating my store with these values. I updated my stripe_customers collection in the console to include a new user, but should the code automatically do this when a user signs in? Sorry if these are very basic questions.

Comment: Its all good. I've added an answer below to clarify. if it works please accept it. To output your values to a local store i.e. runtimeconfig.json file run this:          firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json

Comment: Have you checked on your Stripe dashboard to make sure your requests to create a customer and setup intent have worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you've supplied (below) implies that the key in your config isn't been pulled into your code. If you're running this locally you need to run the below any time you change your functions:config values.

```
 firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json
```

Check the [doc's](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) out about how to run your function locally:

Error

> "Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardSetup intent secret: value should
> be a client_secret string. You specified: undefined"

Comment: thanks so much for your help, I'm now getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: firebase.firestore(...).useEmulator is not a function. I cannot find this error specific to the emulator online, really appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're trying to achieve or what you have run to get this error. To invoke an onCreate function locally use `myFirestoreFunction({foo: ‘new’})` 
you can start the shell with `firebase functions:shell` . Don't forget to export your credentials for the firestore you are trying to access. Check this out page for help, https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell#invoke_firestore_functions